# Delete a header in PHP

Tags: php, caching, header

To allow caching a PHP generated file, I want to make sure, that the 'Pragma: no-cache' header is **not** set. However, how do I delete a possibly already set header?

That is, it *could* be possible, that somewhere in the code someone wrote `header('Pragma: no-cache');` and now I want to make sure, the header is not sent.

Is it sufficient to do this:

```
header('Pragma:');
```

or is there something like `delete_header()` (which would, apparently, be undocumented or well-hidden)?

Comment: Since PHP is open source software, it'd be nonsense to have something "undocumented and well hidden" in there.

Comment: @Techpriester: I know dozens of completely undocumented OS projects, and well-hidden may also be unintentional.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[header_remove()](http://www.php.net/header_remove) since php 5.3

[header_register_callback()](http://www.php.net/header_register_callback) is also coming soon

Comment: Cool, thanks. It's a pity, that the PHP boys thought of this just recently (after all, HTTP handling is a core application area of PHP).

Comment: What are the solutions for before php 5.3? I currently have PHP/5.2.17

Comment: @Pacerier for php < 5.3.0 "header('Pragma:');" does the job. The browser doesn't receive any 'Pragma' header (even blank).

Comment: @maliayas. I tested it. What you said is not true. The browser receives a blank header. Adding a blank header is not removing header at all!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old and already answered.  But some of the answers could leave folks with the wrong impression.  Rest assured that if your response headers contain `Pragma: no-cache` it absolutely will in fact prevent a web browser from caching a resource regardless of other settings.

So of course if you are using at least PHP 5.3, you can remove the `Pragma` header using `header_remove( 'Pragma' );`.

Answer (score 2):

You can override a previously set header by passing a second argument to `header()`:

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

Check the [manual for `header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I know that, but the question is, if this is sufficient, i.e., if providing just 'Pragma:' for header() will erase it from the list of sent ones.

Comment: @Boldewyn No it won't erase it from the list of sent ones. It would override it with no value, which means although the intended outcome is the same, we are sending unnecessary bytes since we will still have to send the string "Pragma:" over the wire.

Answer (score 1):

The 'pragma' headers behaviours are not defined by the spec - despite the widely held believe that sending a 'Pragma: No-cache' header will have some effect on the browser, in fact it is almost universally ignored (and is never returned by any php installation I've used).

To tell the browser NOT to cache content is done via an expires header with a date in the past, a Cache-Control header with a no-cache value, or (if you want to be sneaky) by a 'Varies: Date' header. In the absence of any of these types of header the client must not cache the page.

So, conversely, if you want a page to be cacheable, set the expires and cache-cntrol headers.

C.

Comment: This does not answer the question.. The question is about "Delete a header in PHP" not on how to implement caching.

Comment: No - that's the title of the question however what the OP is trying to achieve is to make the content cacheable - deleting a pragma header has no relevance to this

Comment: the question is "how do I delete a possibly already set header?"

Comment: You are reading too much into it. The title of the question describes the question.

Comment: I think this is no longer the case.