# How to remove a header in PHP below 5.3?

Tags: php, header, http-headers

How do we remove a header (e.g. `Last-Modified`) that has already been set but not yet sent over the wire?

(It may have been set by Apache, "pre"-PHP, and whatnot.)

I'm currently using PHP 5.2.17 and [`header_remove`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2572152/632951) is an undefined function.

To be clear, I do not want to send a blank header line like `header("Foo-bar:")`. I want to completely remove it from the output buffer and **send nothing**.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel. Having a blank header line will mean we are sending a blank header line over the wire to the client. Unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar Auto-set by some configuration settings of the webhost

Comment: @Pacerier do you have mod_rewrite installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and modify `.htaccess`

```
Header unset Last-Modified
```

Comment: It seems to work with some headers but not with others. I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work with `Server` and `Date`, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Update your PHP version or ask your hoster to update it. PHP 5.2 was EOLed several months ago and thus will not receive any further bug or security fixes. If you are 5.2 you are a security threat to yourself and everybody visiting your site. Updating your PHP version will additionally give you all the new features and performance improvements.

Apart from that: Restructure your logic so that the header isn't set in the first place. There is no way to completely remove the header in 5.2.

Comment: I mean that's not part of my code, so I can't restructure the logic in anyway.